# How do I create a Windows Service using Threading and multiple HttpWebRequest async calls?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, windows-services, httpwebrequest

I need help with creating a windows service using Threading and asynchronous HttpWebRequest calls.  I have created a few C# windows services before but never using threading.  Also, I seem to be getting hung up with the async calls using HttpWebRequest.  I have googled this as well as looking on this site.  I could not find anything that helped.  This is mainly because I could not seem to get what was presented in other questions to work in my specific example.

Please keep in mind that I may be overlapping things based on my lack of knowledge in this specific area as well as through trying to figure it out.

The main flow of this is to get a list of urls during onStart.  Typically this list would be retrieved from a _facade.GetUrls call.  Then, at each time interval call scanSites. A request is made to each url and then I save the results to the database in _facade.SaveUrlResponse.

My problems is it seems as if I am caught in an endless loop when I debug it.  I am not exactly sure how/where to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using URLValidation.BusinessManager.Facade;
using URLValidation.BusinessManager.Model;

namespace URLValidation
{
partial class URLValidation : ServiceBase
{
    #region " class variables "        
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private List<UrlModel> _url_List = null;
    private Facade _facade;
    private Thread _t;
    private int _x;
    #endregion


    public URLValidation()
    {
        _facade = new Facade();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _url_List = new List<UrlModel>
                   {
                     new UrlModel(address: "http://www.google.com", addressID: 1),
                     new UrlModel(address: "http://www.microsoft.com", addressID: 2),
                    new UrlModel(address: "http://www.stackoverflow.com", addressID: 3)
                   };

            resetTimer();

            GC.KeepAlive(_timer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void resetTimer()
    {
        try
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 10000;//1800000; //30 minutes
            _timer.Start();
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Elapsed += scanSites;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void scanSites(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _x = 0;
        _t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(scanSites));
        _t.IsBackground = true;
        _t.Start();
    }

    private void scanSites()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (UrlModel url in _url_List)
            {
                _x += 1;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.Address);
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel(request, url);

                IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(saveUrlResponse), requestModel);
                ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
                    (
                                    result.AsyncWaitHandle,
                                    new WaitOrTimerCallback(ScanTimeoutCallback),
                                    requestModel,
                                    (30 * 1000),  // 30 second timeout
                                    true
                    );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void saveUrlResponse(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //grab the custom state object
        RequestModel requestModel = (RequestModel)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)requestModel.Request;

        //get the Response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

        // process the response...
        ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel(request, response, requestModel.UrlModel.AddressID);
        _facade.SaveUrlResponse(responseModel);
    }

    private void ScanTimeoutCallback(object requestModel, bool timedOut)
    {
        if (timedOut)
        {
            RequestModel reqState = (RequestModel)requestModel;
            if (reqState != null)
                reqState.Request.Abort();
        }

        if (_x == _url_List.Count)
        {
            resetTimer();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    }
}
}
```

Okay, I think I am getting somewhere.  I have moved my code to a console app.  I am able to get the results saved to the database by using either GetResponse (sync) and  BeginGetResponse (async).  From what I can tell I believe this is a good solution.  Can somebody verify this and let me know if you foresee any problems once this is moved to a Windows Service.  Here is the new code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static List<UrlModel> _url_List = null;
        private static Object _acctLock = new object();
        private static Facade _facade = new Facade();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _url_List = new List<UrlModel>
                {
                    new UrlModel(address: "http://www.microsoft.com", addressID: 1),
                    new UrlModel(address: "http://www.google.com", addressID: 2),
                    new UrlModel(address: "http://www.stackoverflow.com", addressID: 3)
                };

            lockThreadAndGetUrlStatus(_url_List);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void lockThreadAndGetUrlStatus(List<UrlModel> _url_List)
        {
            Thread[] threads;
            try
            {
                threads = new Thread[_url_List.Count];
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "main";
                int i = 0;
                foreach (UrlModel url in _url_List)
                {
                    //Thread t = new Thread(() => scanSites(url));
                    Thread t = new Thread(() => scanSitesWithAsync(url));
                    t.Name = i.ToString();
                    threads[i] = t;
                    i += 1;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < _url_List.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} Alive : {1}", threads[i].Name, threads[i].IsAlive);
                    threads[i].Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} Alive : {1}", threads[i].Name, threads[i].IsAlive);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Current Priority : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Priority);
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} Ending", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        static void scanSitesWithAsync(UrlModel url)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (_acctLock)
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.Address);
                    request.Method = "HEAD";
                    RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel(request, url);

                    IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(saveUrlResponseWithAsync), requestModel);
                    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
                    (
                                result.AsyncWaitHandle,
                                new WaitOrTimerCallback(scanTimeoutCallback),
                                requestModel, 30000, true
                    );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        static void saveUrlResponseWithAsync(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestModel requestModel = (RequestModel)result.AsyncState;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)requestModel.Request;

                //get the Response
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

                // process the response...
                ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel(requestModel.Request, response, requestModel.UrlModel.AddressID);
                _facade.SaveUrlResponse(responseModel);
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        static void scanTimeoutCallback(object requestModel, bool timedOut)
        {
            try
            {
                if (timedOut)
                {
                    RequestModel reqState = (RequestModel)requestModel;
                    if (reqState != null)
                        reqState.Request.Abort();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: what problem are you having? Do you have a stack trace of the error?

Comment: It seems to go through the process a few times and then errors out.  I am having a hard time keeping track of it as the debugger moves to different threads.  I just did a quick Google and it seems I need to use the Debug ... Window ... Thread and the Debug Location while in debug mode to narrow it down.  I will let you know what I find.  Thanks.

Comment: The 1st time works, values are saved to the DB.  The 2nd time the values are also saved but the error is also thrown.  Although the error points to the EndGetRequest I am pretty sure my problem is the way I am resetting the _x variable as well as handling the thread.  The problem is when I try to work through it I end up getting lost.
Message = "The request was aborted: The request was canceled."
StackTrace = "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at URLValidation.saveUrlResponse(IAsyncResult result) in \\URLValidation\\URLValidation.cs:line 110"

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas? My latest attempt I tried to use an array of threads.  Then, after digging some more I realized that I should use ThreadPool instead.  I haven't started down that path yet, mainly because my head is spinning.  Here is a crude list of what I am trying to accomplish.
1. C# Windows Service: OnStart gets a list of urls.
2. Timers.Timer elapse: stop timer & call function w/ thread for ea url.
3. This function makes Async call w/ BeginGetResponse.
4. AsyncCallBack saves results and cleans ea thread.
5. After all is done start the timer again.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have modified the code and moved it to a console app. I believe it is working now.  The code and details are in the 2nd code block above.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are trying to issue 3 async requests at the same time. By default, the HTTP/1.1 protocol only specifies 2 connections

Comment: Thanks.  I did some research based on your reply.  The default connection limit is 2 but that value can be changed as needed.  However, I thought that since I am using the lock along with the Async HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse I thought that would prevent the number of concurrent calls from being more than 1 at a time.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Bueller ... Bueller ... :)  Does anybody have anything that will help?

Comment: While you do have a lock around the code that creates threads, there is nothing around the begingetresponse(). This means that you can have more than 2 BeginGetResponse calls active at the same time which is where your problem is. Also, I dont understand what you are trying to do. Why are you using Threads along with async, and then trying to limit it to one outstanding?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will take a look and get back to you.  Since this is my first time working with threads some of the reason may just be from lack of experience.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on something else now.  As soon as I get back on this I will take a look and respond.  I appreciate your feedback!!